# C++ My program has confused me greatly

Tags: c++

Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <cstdlib> // for rand() and srand()
#include <ctime>
using namespace 
int main()
{
   //cout << "How many players?" << endl;
    int numplayers=1;
   //cin >> numplayers;

    int players[numplayers];
    int x=0,y=0;
    srand(time(0));
    x=(rand() % 6 + 1);
    y=(rand() % 6 + 1);
    players[1]=players[1]+x+y;
    cout << ("Your score is" + players[1]) << endl;
    cin >> numplayers;       
}
```

Ok My original problem was that this always crashed, now it prints "@"???

Comment: This is not well-formed C++.

Comment: You explicitly create an array of length 1 and then try to access the second element...

Comment: yeah im just starting out with c++.. :)

Comment: You mean to use `cout << "Your score is: " << players[0] << endl;`

Comment: One problem with updated code is you create an array of size 1. I would use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem like a reusable question

Comment: The question doesn't say `Player[1]`. Don't alter the question to fit the answer!

Comment: @Colonbracket  **Do not use variable length arrays**.  They are not standard, and also lead to other issues (like blowing out the stack if the number of entries in the array is too large).  Instead use `std::vector`.  If you had used `std::vector` (along with `at()` to access your items), you wouldn't have gotten a segmentation fault, but instead, this error, [explicitly stating what's wrong](http://ideone.com/g3YEso).

Comment: I upvoted your question because I don't see many programs that people write that confuse them.  I like to believe that people write programs that they can understand (or only use features that they understand).

Answer (score 3):

C++ arrays are 0 based.

`players[1]` is accessing a location outside the range of the array.

You will want: `players[0]`.

Comment: While that would fix the problem, it isn't what you want. When you try to access the array for the first player, you want to access players[0]. For the second player, it would be players[1].

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting, that the fix is to adjust the index, instead of - say - stop the entire array-of-size-1 madness?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it crashes for the below line:

```
players[1]=players[1]+x+y;
```

Because size of `players` array is 1, so it has only index **0**. And in above line, it tries to access index **1**. Take a look at [Buffer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and array index out of bounds.

- Try to define an array with constant size.
- If you need a dynamic array, use linked list or vector.

Comment: Using extra space to avoid access overflow is not the best advice, you should be able to create an array of a desired size and use it properly by indexing from 0 to arraySize - 1

Comment: Sorry the code i gave in my post was outdated and has now been updated. I had already changed it to player[0], but thanks for being helpful. However now it just prints out a "@" instead of the message?

Comment: *"Which causes Access Overflow for the program."* - No. It's undefined behavior. You cannot produce a definitive answer to a construct, that isn't defined. *"Always take some extra indices in case of array size to avoid access overflow."* - Now frankly, **that** was the reason to down vote on this proposed answer. You cannot possibly be serious about this.

Comment: I appreciate the mention of "taking extra spaces", I have updated the answer. Always used to take extra spaces, but after all it's really a bad idea, I should not have included that into my answer.

Comment: Still bogus, I mean, what the hell is an *"Access Overflow"*? A library granting too much access to an object, so that the client code overflows? And a statement that attributes verifiable and reproducible outcome to code that exhibits undefined behavior is just wrong, no matter how you slice it.

Comment: I have got your point and updated the answer. Also I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why) very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << ("Your score is" + players[1]) << endl;
```

Here you're trying to use direct string concatenation, but you can't concatenate a string literal with an integer like that. You end up doing pointer arithmetic, which is definitely not what you intended.

You should instead use `cout`'s built-in formatting:

```
cout << "Your score is" << players[1] << endl;
```

Your next problem is that `players` is not declared correctly; an array cannot have runtime bounds, and `numplayers` (despite having only the one initial value) is ultimately a "runtime" variable. You would be better off with a `std::vector` if the size of the array is going to change later; otherwise make `numplayers` a `constexpr`.

Your last problem is that, if the array declaration *were* valid, you'd be trying to access the second element of a one-element array! The first element is `players[0]`, not `players[1]`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the array is declared correctly, it couldn't be a member without const size, and if the size is too large for stack it could fail. Probably not a good habit to do, agreed, but I'm not sure there is anything incorrect about it in this, or original, context.

Comment: @TimBeaudet: It's definitely incorrect. Arrays cannot have runtime bounds.

Comment: @TimBeaudet: And it's not a member :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you're doing not good.

- I believe you're using C++, there is no known way to me about creating arrays of dynamic size i.e. `int players[numplayers]`. In C++ either we can create array of fixed size i.e. `int players[10]` or use *pointer* to an array for dynamically allocated memory e.g. `int* players = new int[numplayers]`. This allocates an array of size `numplayers` and an *int pointer* named players is pointing to it. We can use this pointer as normal array e.g. printing 1st index of array is written as `player[0]` or another syntax is `*(player + 0)`. Remember to delete this dynamically allocated memory at the end of program i.e. `delete[] player`.
- Second thing is when you have allocated an array and are using its value for computation, always initialize it to 0 as newly allocated array contains garbage value and it will affect your computations. code for initializing it to zero may be like this:

Here is the loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < numplayers ; i++){
    player[i]=0;
    //another syntax is : *(player + i) = 0;
}
```

- *C++* does not concat as you did in your `std::cout` statement. Make it like this:
  `cout << "Your score is" << players[0] << endl;`
- In C++, arrays always start with index zero, so 1st index will be 0 in this case. So your program will work well if it is like this:

  ```
  int numplayers = 1;
  int* players = new int[numplayers];
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  srand(time(0));
  x = (rand() % 6 + 1);
  y = (rand() % 6 + 1);
  players[0] = 0;
  players[0] = players[0] + x + y;
  cout << "Your score is" << players[0] << endl;
  delete[] players;

  return 0;
  ```